# Cannot Create a Group, Invalid Scope

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create a group with the following dot.net code:

```
var groupDef = new Group()
{
    DisplayName = name,
    MailNickname = name + " " + GetTimestamp(),
    Description = "Group/Team created for testing purposes",
    Visibility = "Private",
    GroupTypes = new string[] { "Unified" }, // same for all teams
    MailEnabled = true,                      // same for all teams
    SecurityEnabled = false,                 // same for all teams

    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        ["owners@odata.bind"] = owners.Select(o => $"{graphV1Endpoint}/users/{o.Id}").ToArray(),
        ["members@odata.bind"] = members.Select(o => $"{graphV1Endpoint}/users/{o.Id}").ToArray(),
    }
};

// Create the modern group for the team
Group group = await graph.Groups.Request().AddAsync(groupDef);
```

I am getting a "Method not allowed." error thrown on the last line shown (Group group = await ...).

The scope parameter for the auth provider contains "Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All".

If I add Group.Create to the scope I get an error stating the scope is invalid. Reducing the scope to just "Group.Create" also gives an error.

It certainly appears that I cannot create a group without Group.Create in the scope, but that throws an error at sign in.

Microsoft.Graph is version 3.19.0

Microsoft.Graph.Core is version 1.22.0

Comment: The app has all of the Group API permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up serializing the object and making the Http call with my own code. Basically, something like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupDef, jsonSettings);
Group group = HttpPost<Group>("/groups", json);
```

No permissions were changed.